# GDPR Data Privacy Policy

Tags: gdpr

In the framework of setting up our Data Processing Register, could you kindly provide us with your Data Privacy Policy, please ?
Thank you

Comment: In this forum community members answer questions. Your question seems to be aimed at the CiviCRM LLC? In that case it would make more sense to send an email to info@civicrm.org as almost no one on this forum would be in a position to provide you with what you are asking for.

Comment: I think some of this may need answering by your hosting provider

Comment: I am fairly sure it does. And remember telling Cecile so about a year ago :-)

Comment: Or are you asking for examples from others for examples of their Data Privacy Policy? Not quite clear what you want!

Answer (score 4):

CiviCRM -as the software- doesn't have a privacy policy, because it doesn't hold any personal data.

Your specific instance of that software, as installed on your server or hosted by one of your provider does store personal data. Check with your provider if they have a privacy policy.

However, the privacy policy depends on what personal data you collect and what your organisation does with it, so you are likely to have to adjust based on your own unique way of using CiviCRM.

While you detail that, may I suggest you to look at how your CiviCRM might be connected to other providers, for instance to process the credit card donations or to send your emails? you will need to check what personal data of your contacts you share with them to let them perform the service, and clearly explain that in your privacy policy.

And lastly, we found the easiest way to be GDPR compliant is to be enforce data minimisation, eg only collect the data you need and know/explain why you collect it (and get consent!). For instance, are you really calling your contacts? if not, it's probably simplier and safer to remove the phone field.

Good luck!